# How can i get label and values based on changed the picklist values?

Tags: picklist

My requirement is I need to get label name and values based on changed the pick list values display the attachment. For example stage field(pick list)have in opportunity each and every pick list values related label and values. If I change the stage field it display the old pick list label and values. Please find the below images.

[image]

Attachment Like below:

Opportunity Name: Jansi

Account Name: catherine

Type: Existing Customer - Upgrade

Lead Source: Purchased List

Please can anyone suggest me what should I do and how?

Comment: Question is unclear to me, can you please elaborate what you need at for Opportunity Stage?

Comment: now stage field have closed won it's having label and values ok. If I change stage field for other it will display related closed won label and values to attachment above I have mentioned.

Comment: Still not clear, about display related closed won label and values
for closed won 
label is Stage and Value is ClosedWon
Now if I change Stage to New  what you want to display ?

Comment: for changing pick list old label values display to attachment.. These values are closed won related values: please see  above images what values stage field closed won.Opportunity Name: Jansi, Account Name: catherine, Type: Existing Customer - Upgrade
Lead Source: Purchased List